# Every representation of a $C^*$-algebra lifts to a representation of double dual $A^{**}$

Tags: representation-theory, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a $ C^*$-algebra and $\pi: A \to B(H)$ be a representation of $A$.

> Does there exist a representation $\tilde{\pi}$ of $A^{\ast \ast}$ such that $\tilde{\pi} \vert_{A}=\pi$

Any ideas/ references?

Comment: Where does this question come from? It doesn't seem like something you would ask if you don't already know the answer.

Comment: @MaoWao: It’s used in section $4$ of [this](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1998-350-05/S0002-9947-98-02190-4/S0002-9947-98-02190-4.pdf) paper.

Comment: Then you should include this context in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The double dual $A^{**}$ is realized as a von Neumann algebra via the *Universal Representation*. That is, $A^{**}=\pi_U(A)''$, where $\pi_U$ is the universal representation. The "universality" in the universal representation comes from the fact that is satisfies a *universal* property. Said property is the following:

> Given a representation $\pi:A\to B(H)$, there exists a normal representation $\tilde\pi:A^{**}\to B(H)$ such that $$ \tilde\pi\circ\pi_U=\pi.$$

This is done for instance on Lemma III.2.2 and Theorem III.2.4 of Takesaki's *Theory of Operator Algebras I*.